# How to combine mixamo animations to start with same position

Tags: animation, mixamo

The character does not continue moving from the end of the previous animation, but starts moving again, how can I fix this?

**Video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/15lSPCMzrSaKpZ38LrQDuT6erqL9lKos1/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You could parent the armature to an empty and move the empty so that the armature will be at the good location when action 2 begins but it doesn't fix the fact that there's no transition between acion 1 and 2, if you don't care then the empty is the solution

Comment: When the first animation is over, the second one should start from the same place and not go to the beginning

Comment: Yes, I understand, you can parent the armature to an empty and move the empty so that it's at the good location at the beginning of action 2, but it doesn't fix the problem that there is no transition between action 1 and 2, if you don't understand what I mean I can propose an answer

Comment: What do you mean by saying "there is no transition"

Comment: Can you send a blender project with your solution of this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Guy from blenderartists found one more solution how to resolve this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIP8QibQ7XU

Comment: Again, I know it's been a long time, but still, recently while browsing youtube, I came across this video and with it I solved my problem in better way. P.S. Its best solution what I found (it works for all animaton, in place/not in place) Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK7sc7tovc0

Answer (score 2):

At frame 1 parent the armature to an empty, keyframe the location of the empty:

[image]

At frame 85 keyframe again:

[image]

At frame 86 move the empty until it puts the armature at the correct location, keyframe the empty:

[image]

Here is the result, as you see it's only a quick fix as the transition between action 1 and 2 is brutal:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add a transition?

Comment: i don't think you will get a transition, because you somehow have keyframed the armature object positions. You normally won't do that, but animate ONLY bones. Then the transitions would also work.

Comment: You could try to copy paste the last pose of action 1 into the action 2, but as Chris, says, it's not easy to fix because of the way the action is set , but I may miss an easy solution

Comment: I only increased the running time in the same way as in the video, could it have affected?

Comment: **Video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhxPzLXdiK0m0JTYrBNzOYueEZQNccW2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I checked the animation without increasing the running time, it didn't help, so I think it doesn't affect.

Comment: By the way I downloaded not in place animation from mixamo, I dont know does it affect or no

Comment: Like this one: https://imgur.com/a/YrkZb9Z

Comment: The problem is the way the armature and the action is set, I can't think of an esay fix but maybe someone will have an idea

Comment: I didn't check the box for "In place"

Comment: OK so try with the In Place option and share the file again

Comment: All the same...

Comment: **Video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JyJ0Q1GxD_2gf4ZsC1BaYmtFSK19eQ1Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: **Blender project:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cgg4VRl4YRfoxoWznMYVP7dVJnqyx1nA/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Yes but also need to import the second action with the same In Place option

Comment: There is no this option: http://imgur.com/a/ITViJLI

Comment: Cool so maybe give an answer in the Add answer field?

Answer (score -2):

I found video with solution of this problem, but the first animation should be “in place”: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NrsSdEUSWI

Comment: Hello, Михаил Байраков, Glad you have a solution, and thanks for your contribution! However, to qualify as an SE answer, a post should be self-contained for the archive, not entirely dependent on external links that may break. Please expand your answers to include a concise plain-language description of the methods in the videos. Otherwise. I'm afraid they may be closed as incomplete. This is nothing personal, it's just the way the site tries to work as an enduring archive of helpful answers.